# Клиент-сервер в Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Я создал консольный клиент-сервер и теперь нужно сделать его в Tkinter. Создал методы для отправки и приёма текста но окно Tk не открывается. Вот код:

client:

```
from socket import *  


class Client(object):

    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self.__host = host
        self.__port = port
        self.__address = (self.__host, self.__port)
        self.__client = None

    def connect(self):
        if self.__client is None:
            self.__client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.__client.connect(self.__address)

    def work(self):
        while True:
            try:
                # 1. Отправка начального сообщения:
                mess = input('Введите сообщение: ')
                data = str.encode(mess)
                self.connect()
                self.__client.send(data)
                print('Сообщение отправлено')

                # 2. Получение ответа сервера:
                data = self.__client.recv(1024)
                response = bytes.decode(data)
                print(response)

                # 3. Отключение от сервера:
                self.__client.close()
                self.__client = None

                # 4. Проверка цикла перезапуска:
                stop = input('Работаем дальше (y/n)? - ')
                if stop == 'n':
                    print('Клиент остановлен')
                    break
            except Exception as err:
                print(f'Ошибка соединения: {err}')
                break
```

server:

```
from socket import *  
from time import ctime


class Server(object):

    def __init__(self, host: str, port: int):
        self.__host = host
        self.__port = port
        self.__address = (self.__host, self.__port)
        self.__listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    def config(self):
        self.__listener.bind(self.__address)
        self.__listener.listen(15)

    def work(self):
        self.config()
        while True:
            # 1. Ожидание запросов на соединение:
            print('Сервер находится в режиме ожидания запросов на соединение ...')
            conn, client = self.__listener.accept()
            print(f'{ctime()}: получен запрос на соединение от {client}')

            # 2. Получение исходного сообщения от клиента:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            mess = bytes.decode(data)
            print(mess)

            # 3. Отправка подтверждения:
            response = f'Сообщение от клиента: [{mess}] - успешно доставлено'
            data = str.encode(response)
            conn.send(data)

            # 4. Закрытие соединения:
            conn.close()
            if mess == 'STOP_SERVER_01012000':
                print('Сервер остановлен по команде администратора')
                break
```

client_window:

```
from tkinter import *
from socket import *


class ClientWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = Tk()
        self.__frame = Frame(self.__root)
        self.__label = Label(self.__frame)
        self.__entry = Entry(self.__root)
        self.__host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
        self.__port = 10001
        self.__address = (self.__host, self.__port)
        self.__client = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.__connect = self.__client.connect(self.__address)

    def config(self):
        self.__root.title('Клиентское окно')
        self.__root.resizable(False, False)
        self.__label.config(text=str(self.__host), font='Arial 13', fg='purple')
        self.__entry.config()

    def layout(self):
        self.__entry.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.4, relwidth=0.6, relheight=0.3)
        self.__frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
        self.__label.pack(padx=15)

    def work(self):
        message = self.__entry.get()
        data = str.encode(message)
        self.__client.send(data)
        print('Сообщение отправлено')
        data = self.__client.recv(1024)
        response = bytes.decode(data)
        self.__label.config(text=response)

    def open(self):
        self.config()
        self.layout()
        self.work()
        self.__root.mainloop()
```

server_window:

```
from tkinter import *
from socket import *
from time import ctime


class ServerWindow(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.__root = Tk()
        self.__frame = Frame(self.__root)
        self.__label = Label(self.__frame)
        self.__chat = Text(self.__frame)
        self.__host = gethostbyname(gethostname())
        self.__port = 10001
        self.__address = (self.__host, self.__port)
        self.__listener = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

    def config(self):
        self.__root.title('Серверный модуль')
        self.__root.resizable(False, False)
        self.__label.config(text=str(self.__host), font='Arial 13', fg='purple')
        self.__chat.config(font='Arial 12', fg='navy', width=50, height=20)
        self.__listener.bind(self.__address)
        self.__listener.listen(15)

    def layout(self):
        self.__frame.pack(padx=15, pady=15)
        self.__label.pack(padx=15)
        self.__chat.pack(pady=15)

    def work(self):
        conn, client = self.__listener.accept()
        print(f'{ctime()}: получен запрос на соединение от {client}')
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        mess = bytes.decode(data)
        self.__label.configure(text=mess)
        response = f'Сообщение от клиента: [{mess}] - успешно доставлено'
        data = str.encode(response)
        conn.send(data)

    def open(self):
        self.config()
        self.layout()
        self.work()
        self.__root.mainloop()
```

client_app:

```
from gui.client_window import ClientWindow


if __name__ == '__main__':

    client = ClientWindow()
    client.open()
```

server_window:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    server_win = ServerWindow()
    server_win.open()
```